# Unit testing for circle using nose python

Tags: python-unittest, nose

Define a nose test class 'TestCircleArea', which tests the behavior of the 'area' method, with the following tests:

1. Define a nose test method 'test_circlearea_with_random_numeric_radius', which creates a circle 'c1' with radius 2.5, and check if its computed area is 19.63.
2. Define a nose test method 'test_circlearea_with_min_radius', which creates a circle 'c2' with radius 0, and check if its computed area is 0.
3. Define a nose test method 'test_circlearea_with_max_radius', which creates a circle 'c3' with radius 1000, and check if its computed area is 3141592.65.

I have written the below nose test methods. But it isn't working. Please suggest.

class Circle:

```
def __init__(self,radius):

    if not isinstance(radius,(int,float)):
        raise TypeError("radius must be a number")

    if not 1000>=radius>=0:
        raise ValueError("radius must be between 0 and 1000 inclusive")

    self.radius = radius


def area(self):
    return round(math.pi*self.radius**2,2)

def circumference(self):
    return round(2*math.pi*self.radius,2)
```

class TestCircleArea:

```
def test_circlearea_with_random_numeric_radius(self):
    c1 = Circle(2.5)
    assert_equals(c1.area(),19.63)

def test_circlearea_with_min_radius(self):
    c2 = Circle(0)
    assert_equals(c2.area(),0)

def test_circlearea_with_max_radius(self):
    c3 = Circle(1000)
    assert_equals(c3.area(),3141592.65)
```

Answer (score 0):

class Circle:

```
def __init__(self, radius):
    # Define initialization method:
    self.radius=radius
    if not isinstance(self.radius,(int,float)):
        raise TypeError("radius must be a number")
    elif(self.radius>1000 or self.radius<0):
        raise ValueError("radius must be between 0 and 1000 inclusive")
    else:
        pass

def area(self):
    # Define area functionality:
    y=math.pi*(self.radius**2)
    return round(y,2)

def circumference(self):
    # Define circumference functionality:
    x=math.pi*2*self.radius
    return round(x,2)
```

class TestCircleArea(unittest.TestCase):

```
def test_circlearea_with_random_numeric_radius(self):
    # Define a circle 'c1' with radius 2.5, and check if 
    # its area is 19.63.
    c1 = Circle(2.5)
    self.assertEquals(c1.area(),19.63)

def test_circlearea_with_min_radius(self):
    # Define a circle 'c2' with radius 0, and check if 
    # its area is 0.
    c2 = Circle(0)
    self.assertEquals(c2.area(),0)

def test_circlearea_with_max_radius(self):
    # Define a circle 'c3' with radius 1000.1. and check if 
    # its area is 3141592.65.
    c3 = Circle(1000)
    self.assertEquals(c3.area(),3141592.65)
```